# How do I get the mouse's position off the dialog continuously? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

My question is:
**How do i continuously get the mouse's position even when it isn't on any dialogs, in mfc?**

Comment: One way is to do a MouseCapture - as long as the mouse is captured to your window you will get mouse move messages.

Comment: @Mark [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx) is not a very robust solution. You have no control over when you lose your mouse capture. You get informed when you lost it ([`WM_CAPTURECHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645605.aspx)) but you have no control over preventing that from happening. Plus, this is limited to foreground windows.

Comment: @IInspectable, true but the question didn't include enough information to determine if those would be acceptable limitations. The last time I needed such a function (too long ago to remember) it was sufficient.

Comment: @Mark That's true. I guess I read something into the *"continuously"* that isn't there. `SetCapture` could well be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @llnspectable sorry if my question wasn't clear, but i'm trying to track the mouse continuously, so that my dialog box is constantly resizing dependant on the cursor. I want to use the setTimer, as it allows constant update of cursor position outside the dialog box.

Comment: @llnspectable by any chance, could you show me a sample of how setTimer is implemented? because the current documentation of SetTimer is not as clearly defined for me.

Comment: @CodeDoctorJL The link I posted contains sample code. Your requirements are surprising, though. You do not need to query the mouse position to enable dialog resizing - this is handled by the system for you. You don't need to write any code - besides setting the appropriate border style to enable resizing.

Comment: @llnspectable For my case, it is quite different. My application has invisible borders that resize. Currently, they resize when the mouse's LButtonUp is called, but this questions allows me to grow and shrink the dialog. :)

Comment: @CodeDoctorJL In that case you should probably go with `SetCapture`. It is easier to implement, is more responsive to mouse input, and gives a more natural result, e.g. the dialog snapping back to its initial size when it loses focus during a resize operation. Of course, you have full control over this and can implement any other behavior you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always install a [mouse hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It's a bit overkill, but, it will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your specific requirements. If you need to direct mouse input temporarily to a control you can call [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx). This will request the system to send all mouse messages to a specific window until you not longer need it by calling [`ReleaseCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261.aspx), or you lose it, when another window gains input focus. The latter is signaled through a [`WM_CAPTURECHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645605.aspx) message.

If, on the other hand, you need continuous information about mouse positions you can install a timer ([`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf.aspx)) and call [`GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390.aspx).